# Pandas - groupby - get_group with interval/date range

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying use an interval/date range with the get_group() method.

```
ranges = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1900', periods=12, freq='120M')
dates = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['dob'], ranges))
```

I know typically you can use `dates.get_group('groupName')`.
However, since I'm using a date range, I'm unable to get it to work.
Is it possible to use get_group() with a date range/interval?
If so, what is the proper syntax?

My goal is to be able to select a dataframe from a particular group. Maybe there's another way?
Thanks!

Sample Data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sA_EdrBAVuNCcUQRjj09wmaSCUgiAeif/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you provide sample data and your expected output?

Comment: I added the sample data to the bottom. As you can see, I am grouping data by decade. Essentially I want a separate dataframe based on a particular decade.

Comment: Am I doing this all wrong? I just want to separate my data by decade. Should I even be using groupby?

Comment: As I said, please show an example of your expected output. It's unclear to me what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to add the parameter `labels`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dataForStackOverflow.csv', parse_dates=[2])
print (df.head())
     id     last_name        dob
0  1793     Abdelnaby 1968-06-24
1  3299    Abdul-Aziz 1946-04-07
2  3218  Abdul-Jabbar 1947-04-16
3  1753    Abdul-Rauf 1969-03-09
4  1382   Abdul-Wahad 1974-11-03

ranges = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1900', periods=12, freq='120M')

labels = ['{}s'.format(i.strftime('%Y')) for i in ranges[1:]]
print (ranges)
DatetimeIndex(['1900-01-31', '1910-01-31', '1920-01-31', '1930-01-31',
               '1940-01-31', '1950-01-31', '1960-01-31', '1970-01-31',
               '1980-01-31', '1990-01-31', '2000-01-31', '2010-01-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='120M')

print (labels)
['1910s', '1920s', '1930s', '1940s', '1950s', '1960s', '1970s', 
 '1980s', '1990s', '2000s', '2010s']
```

And then create `dictionary of Dataframes` by converting `groupby` object to tuples and dicts:

```
dates = dict(tuple(df.groupby(pd.cut(df['dob'], bins=ranges, labels=labels))))

print (dates['1940s'])
      id last_name        dob
7   3844      Able 1932-07-27
11  3895  Ackerman 1930-09-04
36  3742    Alcorn 1936-10-08

print (dates['1950s'])
      id     last_name        dob
1   3299    Abdul-Aziz 1946-04-07
2   3218  Abdul-Jabbar 1947-04-16
13  3579         Acton 1942-01-11
20  3063         Adams 1949-05-15
21  3178         Adams 1947-11-27
23  3287       Adelman 1946-06-16
30  3417         Aitch 1944-09-21
32  3425          Akin 1944-07-31
```

With no `labels` is possible use [`Interval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Interval.html):

```
dates = dict(tuple(df.groupby(pd.cut(df['dob'], bins=ranges))))

interv = pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('1930-01-31'), pd.Timestamp('1940-01-31'))
print (interv)
(1930-01-31, 1940-01-31]

print (dates[interv])
      id last_name        dob
7   3844      Able 1932-07-27
11  3895  Ackerman 1930-09-04
36  3742    Alcorn 1936-10-08
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. This is useful knowledge. I am hoping this isn't the only way to do this though.

Comment: @csf - added solution with no labels - use `Interval`

Comment: Thanks for your effort @jezrael.